# Asking for input file that contain string in octave

Tags: matlab, csv, input, file-io, octave

I am trying to load data from a csv file. I have been told to use `textscan`,  but when I try to load the file using `csvread` I get the error "undefined near line 1 column 16". I get the same error, but with different column position, when trying to use similar methods such as `fileread` and `textread`.

Here is the link to the csv file
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByD1GZqyS54ZV3ZoVFltYzZ6eE0
and here is a [picture of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBpu4.png).

I know it would be easier to simply remove the other, unwanted content, because I just need the data from columns E, F, G, and K, and could then use `dlmread` or `csvread` on these numeric values.  Still, this does not seem like it should be that hard.  Can you please help me understand how to load string data from a file in with MATLAB or Octave?

Update 08/20/17 (UTC+7)

thanks for the answer, especially from information (this is userid right?)

i think the problem probably cause by the first row that have 26 cells and the other 4 just 20, so i decide to remove data after column K and we have 11 column and then run :

> fid=fopen('tesdata.dat'); %i change the data in csv to dat file
>
> c=textscan(fid,'%f%s%s%s%f%f%d8%s%s%s%f');
>
> fclose(fid);

this works for my case, so i think the problem probably the different column size. well i do think this could work if the file in csv with csvread

Comment: please show your code with textscan and what you've done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `textscan` solution to grab each column as a string.

```
fname = 'katalogisc.csv';   % your file
fid = fopen(fname,'r');    

numCols = 'Z'-'A'+1;  % i.e. 26 columns in this case
scanStr = repmat('%s',1, numCols);  % interpret each column as a string

columnsOfStrings = textscan(fid, scanStr,'delimiter',',');  % split strings by comma (,)

fclose(fid);
```

I like the `xlsread` solution when it works, but get a 'File is not recognized format' error, in this case, on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

[num,txt,raw] = xlsread(filename)

you can use this. use data present in raw

raw{:,5}, raw{:,6}, raw{:,7}, raw{:,11}

is what you need

Comment: it's a CSV, not xls or xlsx. No need to use xlsread form the io package here although it works..